# Modify header in gtsummary merged table

Tags: r, gtsummary

I used a code Sjober showed in a YouTube video to create a merged table. It works well except, but in the final table I am not able to rename my three treatment conditions (they appear as 0,1,2) instead of having the labels I defined. I use `modify_header(update=list(stat_1 ~ Control", ...)`. It looks I need something else to run?

```
# Comparing T/C and newies
#---------------------------
t0 <- t0_clean %>% tbl_summary(by=d, 
                               include = c(d, women, age, lives_with_mother,
                                           ese, starts_with("ames"), who5),
                               label = list(women = "Women", 
                                            age ~ "Age",
                                            lives_with_mother = "Lives with mother",
                                            ese ~ "Emotional Self-Efficacy"),
                               missing = "no",
                               type = list(age ~ "continuous"), # categorical var with >10 cat are treated as categoricals. here we reverse it
                               ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "{level}")

# Table comparing T/C
t1 <- t0_clean %>% 
      filter(d %in% c(0,1)) %>%
      tbl_summary(by=d, 
                  include = c(d, women, age, lives_with_mother,
                              ese, starts_with("ames"), who5),
                  label = list(women = "Women", 
                              age ~ "Age",
                              lives_with_mother = "Lives with mother",
                              ese ~ "Emotional Self-Efficacy"),
                  missing = "no",
                  type = list(age ~ "continuous"), # categorical var with >10 cat are treated as categoricals. here we reverse it
                  ) %>%
      add_p() %>%
      modify_header(p.value ~ gt::md("C vs. T")) %>%
      modify_column_hide(all_stat_cols())

# Table copmaring T/newies
t2 <- t0_clean %>% 
      filter(d %in% c(1,2)) %>%
      tbl_summary(by=d, 
                  include = c(d, women, age, lives_with_mother,
                              ese, starts_with("ames"), who5),
                  label = list(women = "Women", 
                               age ~ "Age",
                               lives_with_mother = "Lives with mother",
                               ese ~ "Emotional Self-Efficacy"),
                  missing = "no",
                  type = list(age ~ "continuous"), # categorical var with >10 cat are treated as categoricals. here we reverse it
      ) %>%
      add_p() %>%
      modify_header(p.value ~ gt::md("T vs. Newies")) %>%
      modify_column_hide(all_stat_cols())       # hide summary stat columns

# merge tables
t_merge <- tbl_merge(list(t0, t1, t2)) %>%
      modify_spanning_header(
            list(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Treatment condition**",
                  starts_with("p.value") ~ "**p-values**")) %>%
      modify_header(update = list(stat_1 ~ "Control",
                                  stat_2 ~ "Treated",
                                  stat_3 ~ "Outsiders"))
```

This is my result, and I want to change the labels 0,1,2 below the "Treatment condition".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gIoG.jpg)

Comment: Use the `gtsummary::show_header_names()` function to show the underlying column names. Then use `modify_header()` function to change the headers.